# Saving User Information with Parse on different View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I was wondering if anybody knows how to save data to the same User on Parse by entering information on different ViewControllers? I would like for the user to be able to Sign-Up on 1 View Controller, then answer some questions on the next ViewController, and having all the information be saved under that user? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that, depends on what approach of saving information you are going with. If you just want to pass values from the first view controller to the second one, then it is very simple.

One example of how to do it is here: 
http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2014/05/29/passing-data-between-view-controllers-ios-obj-c.aspx

**UPDATE:**

Keep in mind that with that approach you won't have any saved data... In order to save it properly, I would suggest to use SQLite or some database to manage users data.

Comment: I was looking more on how to save the information to the same Parse user, instead of passing it. Ex: "SignUpViewController1 has user.username = username.text , user.password = password.text" then on the "ProfileViewController would have user["phoneNumber"] = phone.text , user["age"] = age.text" ... So I need all that information saved to the same user through button clicks. Instead of creating 2 separate users or not having the information saved at all.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm going to try and use realm for that then. Realm replaces core data and SQLite, and that looks very easy to use. Thank you a lot for your suggestions. I appreciate it!

Comment: @BrennanHamstra I'm glad I could help.